# Algorithm for arbitrary number of nested for loops

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I am trying to figure out an algorithm to generalise my code for an arbitrary integer value of a parameter that in my code controls the number of nested for loops.  My code schematically looks like

```
A = numpy matrix of dimension (n x m)

For i = 0:p
 For j = 0:q
  ...
   For l = 0:z

     X[counter] = A[0]*i + A[1]*j + ... + A[n]*l
     counter = counter + 1

X = numpy matrix of dimension (p*q*...*z x len(A[0]))
```

where the number of for loops is controlled by an arbitrary integer number.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, this will blowup very quickly. However you can use cartesian product iterator:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

# Create a list with ranges:
rngs=np.array([p,q,..,z])

#Initialize X empty
X = np.empty((rngs.prod(), A.shape[0]))

#Cycle over all cartesian products
for i,t in enumerate(itertools.product(*[range(i) for i in rngs])):
    X[i,:] = sum([A[i,:] * t[i] for i in range(len(t))])
```

Test data:

```
A = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))
A
array([[8, 5, 0, 2, 0, 4, 5, 5, 0, 9],
       [7, 0, 5, 9, 9, 4, 8, 2, 6, 8],
       [4, 3, 8, 5, 2, 5, 4, 8, 6, 1],
       [0, 5, 6, 5, 5, 0, 8, 5, 4, 9],
       [3, 3, 2, 6, 6, 9, 7, 7, 3, 3],
       [4, 0, 7, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2],
       [6, 2, 5, 9, 9, 9, 4, 7, 7, 3],
       [6, 3, 4, 9, 0, 3, 8, 1, 6, 8],
       [6, 5, 6, 0, 8, 7, 9, 0, 7, 4],
       [2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 8, 3, 3, 2, 9]])

rngs = np.random.randint(1, 5, size=10)
rngs
array([4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4])

X = np.empty((rngs.prod(), A.shape[0]))

for i,t in enumerate(itertools.product(*[range(i) for i in rngs])):
    X[i,:] = sum([A[i,:] * t[i] for i in range(len(t))])

X
array([[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  2.,   1.,   4., ...,   3.,   2.,   9.],
       [  4.,   2.,   8., ...,   6.,   4.,  18.],
       ...,
       [ 86.,  44.,  64., ...,  64.,  63.,  97.],
       [ 88.,  45.,  68., ...,  67.,  65., 106.],
       [ 90.,  46.,  72., ...,  70.,  67., 115.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This seems like the right direction to go in. However, I cannot quite get it to work yet. Let me be a bit more precise. 
The An's are actually lines in a numpy matrix, i.e. A1=A[0].
I am expecting X to be a matrix of dimensions (len(A[0])) x (p*q*...*z).

Comment: (p*q*...*z) x (len(A[0]))  actually.

Comment: Ok now it is more clear what A's are and I will try to fix my code.

Comment: Thanks. I also edited the original question accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't quite work yet, just returns a matrix of 0's.

Comment: I am adding a data that I am testing with

Comment: A is just a simple matrix, i.e. A = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10)).

Comment: What are A[0], A[1], etc.. then? columns? rows?

Comment: Rows of the matrix A. Sorry that I wasn't more clear.

Comment: Edited again, I can add my test case if needed.

Comment: Because I think X should have size X = np.empty((rngs.prod(), A.shape[1]))

Comment: I hope this is what you expect from it

Answer (score 0):

First up: Are you sure you want to do this? The number of actual statements executed is going to get large very quickly as the number of loops increases, your code is going to be slow with anything other than a very small number of loops, possibly so slow as to make its use impractical. I'd think about whether you really need all those loops.

Leaving that aside, I'd do this recursively:

```
def nextloop(counter, coefficients, vectors):
    counter = counter - 1
    if counter == 0:
        result = 0
        for i in range(len(vectors)):
            result += coefficients[i] * vectors[i]
        return result
    else:
        return nextloop(counter, coefficients, vectors)

finalresult = nextloop(5, coeffs, vecs) # Adjust initial call appropriately
```

This isn't exactly right because I'm not quite clear on what your algorithm does on each loop, but you can amend it as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and useful answer. I am not quite sure what you mean by coefficients. In my example above, the coefficients in the sum for X are the loop variables (counters).

Comment: As I say, I wasn't terribly clear what your code actually did, so my example is unlikely to be exactly what you want. The point is that you can have a function recursively call itself, and you can pass anything you like through as the function arguments. In this case I was anticipating that you'd want to pass your values `A[0]`, `A[1]`, ... `A[n]` along with your vectors (and therefore you'd want a list with the A values and a list of the vectors), but whatever's useful for you!